# Why doesn't SQL2008 interpret the conditional WHERE clause in my stored procedure the way 2005 did?

Tags: sql

My procedure was working fine in a 2005 database, but my PC died and when I set it up again I installed 2008 rather than 2005 - now this procedure doesn't return any results. I ask the question about the difference between the 2 versions simply because I have used this logic before and I haven't changed the procedure since I created it and it was working, the only change has been the fact I am now using SQL 2008

I wrote the procedure in Visual Studio and have noticed that when I paste the select statement into the SQL pane for the table that it is restructured and expanded so that each variation that could be expressed by combining the ANDs and ORs.

What I need is to be able to call this procedure optionally passing either parameter; so if I pass only the componentType it should evaluate the final statement part of the statement and use the value passed - if no value was passed then it would match the IS NULL side of the condition.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.uspSel_ComponentByType(
  @filterText       VARCHAR(50) = NULL 
, @componentType    CHAR(2)     = NULL) 
AS 
SELECT  [pkComponentID], [ComponentType], [ComponentName], [fkSupplierID], [Cost], [WastageCost]
FROM    [tblComponents] AS c INNER JOIN
        [tblSuppliers] AS s ON [c].[fkSupplierID] = [s].[pkSupplierID]
WHERE   ([ComponentName] LIKE @filterText + '%' OR [SupplierName] LIKE @filterText + '%')
 AND    [c].[IsDeleted] = 0
 AND    (@componentType IS NULL OR [ComponentType] = @componentType)
```

Comment: Is the code you posted the procedure as you wrote it, or the proc as restructured by Visual Studio?

Comment: The code is as I wrote it, Visual Studio (and SSMS) restructure it and lay it out differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no SQL pro, but if I understand your intentions right, you should be able to use the sproc with no/either/both parameters and get expected results if you default `@filterText` to `''` instead of `NULL`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.uspSel_ComponentByType(
    @filterText           VARCHAR(50)     = ''      ,
    @componentType        CHAR(2)         = NULL
) 
AS 
    SELECT  ... --the rest of the sproc is unchanged
```

As David M clarified, this is probably because SQL Server 2005 and 2008 handles string concatenation with `NULL` values differently. It seems that in SQL Server 2005

```
'A string' + NULL = 'A string';
```

while in SQL Server 2008

```
'A string' + NULL = NULL;
```

By changing the default to `''`, we made the default comparison `'' + '%'`, which will always be treated as `%` and match everything, instead of `NULL + '%'`, which will end upp `NULL` and match nothing.

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds... ;)

Comment: 'A string' + NULL = NULL in SQL Server 2005. SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: ...and it's been this way since SQL Server 7. What happened is the defaults for connections and new databases have changed from version to version.

Comment: Ah ok, seems that I need to update my approach to this type of problem - the setting will be removed in a future version of SQL Server!
But the empty string default value is really what I was trying to get to and makes more sense (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like different default handling of concatenating a null value - it is now concatenating `NULL` with '%' to give `NULL`, causing the LIKE comparison to fail. If you replace the `NULL` default with an empty string for `@filterText` you have a stored procedure that is not affected by such a difference in behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation David; thinking about it in those terms makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's due to SET options, especially likely is CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, with ANSI_NULLS as a bubbler